# How to implement dictionary with AVL tree?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
class TreeNode:
    """
    Binary tree nodes
    Please complete the internal implementation of the node by yourself and implement the given interface
    """
    def __init__(self, key, val=None):  
        pass

    def getLeft(self):  # Get the left subtree (return None if it does not exist)

    def getRight(self):  # Get the right subtree (return None if it does not exist)
        pass


class mydict:
    """
    Implementing dictionary types using AVL trees
    """
    def getRoot(self):  # Return the internal AVL tree root
        pass

    def __init__(self):  # Create an empty dictionary
        pass

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):  # Save key:value to dictionary
        # md[key]=value
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, key):  # Get the value from the dictionary based on the key
        # v = md[key]
        # If the key does not exist in the dictionary, please raise KeyError
        pass

    def __delitem__(self, key):  # Delete the key from the dictionary
        # del md[key]
        # If the key does not exist in the dictionary, please raise KeyError
        pass

    def __len__(self):  # Get the length of the dictionary
        # l = len(md)
        pass

    def __contains__(self, key):  # Determine if a key exists in the dictionary
        # k in md
        pass

    def clear(self):  # remove dict
        pass

    def __str__(self):  # Output string form, refer to the built-in dict type, output according to the AVL tree LDR traversal
        # print type：{'name': 'sessdsa', 'hello': 'world'}
        pass

    __repr__ = __str__

    def keys(self):  # Return all values, type is a list, in the order of AVL tree LDR traversal
        pass

    def values(self):  # Return all values, type is a list, in the order of AVL tree LDR traversal
        pass


# code end

#mydict=dict
print("=========  Implementing dictionary types using AVL trees =========")
md = mydict()
md['hello'] = 'world'
md['name'] = 'sessdsa'
print(md)  # {'name': 'sessdsa', 'hello': 'world'}

for f in range(1000):
    md[f**0.5] = f

for i in range(1000, 2000):
    md[i] = i**2

print(len(md))  # 2002
print(md[2.0])  # 4
print(md[1000])  # 1000000
print(md['hello'])  # world
print(20.0 in md)  # True
print(99 in md)  # False

del md['hello']
print('hello' in md)  # False
for i in range(1000, 2000):
    del md[i]
print(len(md))  # 1001
for f in range(1000):
    del md[f**0.5]
print(len(md))  # 1
print(md.keys())  # ['name']
print(md.values())  # ['sessdsa']
for a in md.keys():
    print(md[a])  # sessdsa
md.clear()
print(md)  # {}
```

I don't know how to implement dict with AVL trees.

---- Implementing dictionary types using AVL trees ----

1. Implement dictionary types with AVL trees to achieve logarithmic performance for all put/get/in/del operations
2. Use the following class definition to implement at least the following methods
3. key supports at least integer, floating point, string
4. Please call hash(key) as the node key of AVL tree
5. Note that the output order of the `__str__`, keys, values methods is the `LDR(leftchild, data, rightchild)` of the AVL tree traversal order.
6. That is, according to the hash(key) to sort, this is not the same as Python 3.7 dict output order.

Comment: This seems like a homework question. And stackoverflow is not a site where you just ask people to write code for you. Attempt to solve the problem yourself, if you run into a specific problem post here and we will help you solve the issue.

Comment: Also please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to give a look at the book "[Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures using Python](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/index.html)". It gives you both theoretical information and implementation of the main data structures.

Chapter 7 is all about trees and has all details you need to implement an AVL.